# Create a List<A> as GraphQLObjectType

Tags: java, graphql-java

I want to return a list of class `A` objects from my GraphQLDatafetcher. I know I can return a single `A` like this:

```
GraphQLObjectType a = GraphQLAnnotations.object(A.class);
...
GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition().type(a); // omitted boilerplate from query object
```

Now, I want to return a list of `A` so I tried something like this:

```
GraphQLObjectType aList = GraphQLAnnotations.object(List.class);
...
GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition().type(aList); // omitted
```

And this:

```
GraphQLObjectType aList = GraphQLAnnotations.object(new GraphQLList(A.class));
...
GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition().type(aList); // omitted
```

Class `A` is annotated like this:

```
@GraphQLType
public class A {...}
```

First attempt returns null and the second attempt does not compile with `GraphQLList cannot be applied to java.lang.Class<A>`

A workaround is to create a wrapper object that holds the list but it seems like an ugly hack to me. How can I return a list of `A` using [GraphQL java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java/tree/v2.3.0) 2.3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List type isn't a subtype of object type, so you can never make an object type that represents a list. Both of these types are output types, though (list is also an input type). And this should be what you need.

```
GraphQLObjectType a = GraphQLAnnotations.object(A.class);
GraphQLOutputType listOfA = new GraphQLList(a);
```

You can then use this type as a field type, as you would a `GraphQLObjectType`:

```
GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition().type(listOfA);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am curious on how I get the variable `typeRepresentingA`? I tried implementing a `GraphQLType` and return  `A.class.getName()` in the `getName()` method.

Comment: @span But... You already have that. I modified my example. I'm not really familiar with graphql-java-annotations, so I just copied your code.

Comment: Ah, I see! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to do the following:

`GraphQLFieldDefinition.newFieldDefinition().type(new GraphQLList(A));`